# dependency qt.core not found for product

Tags: qt, qbs

I get a lot of same errors when try to compile my project using qbs.

Like this:

```
Dependency "Qt.core" not found for product "dist".
Please create a Qt profile using the qbs-setup-qt tool if you haven't already done so.
Product 'dist' had errors and was disabled.
```

I use QtCreator. Should I "create a new Qt profile using the qbs-setup-qt tool"?
Please, can you explain what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Qt Creator sets up the profiles automatically. The most common cause for this message is that the Kit you are using does not have a (valid) Qt version set. Please verify this first. If everything looks okay in that regard, please file an issue at bugreports.qt.io, and we will take it from there.

Comment: Good day! Thank you!
The problem is "No valid kits found". Default kit doesn't have the "Qt version" and requires qmake file. Doesn't Qt Creator has this file?

Comment: Qt and Qt Creator are two separate things. If you got Qt Creator from the Qt installer, it will typically have a Qt version set up (unless you de-selected all Qt versions in the installer). If you have a stand-alone Qt Creator, you might need to point it to a Qt version on your system, which you might need to install first. For instance, on a Linux system, this would be a package called something like "qt5base-dev". If you are new to Qt Creator, I suggest reading https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-configuring.html for more insight into how Kits work and how they are related to Qt versions.